# IE11 missing DOM elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11

I've written a simple extension for OpenCart platform. The extension generates a table with product options that can be sorted and searched.
The options are inserted in the database and the table is generated at the backend - using PHP.

It looks something like this.
[image]

I've tested the extension with **Chrome,FF, IE10 and Edge** and it works fine.
Here is the problem: when using **IE11** **the rows of the table are empty**. When I examined the DOM I found out that there is no content between the "TR" tags. The rows are generated, but the Table Data is gone.

Given that the content is generated at the backend **why does it disappear in IE11?**

**Live url: http://www.stroyland.ru/index.php?route=product/product&path=57&product_id=198**

DOM with Chrome[image]
DOM with IE11 [image]

Comment: You need to at the very least post your HTML code if you want somebody to diagnose this for you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: To start with, your HTML shows some mismatched start/end tags.

Comment: I've updated the post with live demo and screenshots.

Comment: The page also shows a cross domain access issue on IE11 (just look in the console for errors).  If the table is being filled in with an ajax call, that could explain why no data.

Comment: No, the table doesn't use AJAX calls.

Comment: What version of OC are you using?

Comment: Look at the actual source sent to the browser (right click view source). What you see in console is what the browser is interpreting not necessarily what you sent it. If you have bad markup the browser will do what it *thinks* you meant. Validate your HTML if you want it to work across browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the pager plugin of the tablesorter plugin.
There is already an open issue on github for this bug:

https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/issues/54

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try to find another plugin that works in IE11

Comment: There is a fix mentioned in the comments of the issue.

Comment: I just added it and it works. I'll do so more testing to make sure that it doesn't break in any other browser. Thanks again.